# React.js outputs to the jsc: ReferenceError: <component> is not defined

Tags: reactjs

I'm using the `react-rails` gem in a rails project. While `javascript` and `jsx` works consistently, my `coffeescript` files never seem to work. Note that I'm trying to use a pure `coffeescript` solution, with no interpolated jsx.

In my `coffeescript` file (its extension is `*.js.coffee` )

```
{div} = React.DOM

Hello = React.createClass
  render: ->
    (div {}, ['Hello ' + @props.name])
```

In my view:

```
= react_component 'Hello', name: 'World'
```

And this is the error I consistently get in my console:

```
ReferenceError: Hello is not defined
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Taken from my GitHub [issue](https://github.com/facebook/react-rails/issues/28) in the `react-rails` repo, jakubmal answered:

> CoffeeScript creates a closure, which will likely look like:
>
> ```
> (function() {
>   var div, hello;
>
>   div = React.DOM.div;
>
>   Hello = React.createClass({
>     render: function() {
>       return div({}, ['Hello ' + this.props.name]);
>     }
>   });
> }).call(this);
> ```
>
> making `Hello` inaccessible outside the closure.
>
> What you could do is to assign `Hello` to window like:
>
> ```
> window.Hello = React.createClass
> ```
>
> or using a shortcut/trick:
>
> ```
> @Hello = React.createClass
> ```
>
> To keep your app structure clean, you will need to apply at least a
>   namespace pattern here.
>   http://addyosmani.com/blog/essential-js-namespacing/

Additionally, in the `react-rails` google group, Paul O'Shannessy wrote:

> The helper is pretty naive and expects your components to be available as globals. Coffeescript wraps each file in a closure before they get joined by sprockets which violates the global assumption. This came up during development but we decided something for some people would be better than nothing for anybody.